# Django destroys group by statement adding the PK

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a simple task which I currently not able to get designed using the Django QuerySet. The following model is used:

```
class Accountdata(models.Model):
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
bookingdate = models.DateField()
renter = models.ForeignKey(Renter, null=True, blank=True)
```

All I want to do is create a group by which sums up all the amount payed by the renter per month (renter can pay multiple times a month)

I used the following QuerySet (for one specific renter):

```
Accountdata.objects.filter(renter_id=16).annotate(month=TruncMonth('bookingdate'), amountSum=Sum('amount')).values('month', 'amountSum').order_by()
```

Unfortunately the result is wrong. 
I figured out that Django adds the primary key into the group by clause (used the QuerySet "query" methode to see what is going on):

> SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', "accountdata"."bookingdate") AS "month", SUM("accountdata"."amount") AS "amountSum" FROM "accountdata" WHERE "accountdata"."renter_id" = 16 GROUP BY **"accountdata"."id"**, DATE_TRUNC('month', "accountdata"."bookingdate")'

I do not kow why Django is doing this since I do not have the ID inside the "values" section of the QuerySet.
Using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
AccountData.objects.filter(
    renter__id=16
).annotate(
    month=TruncMonth('bookingdate')
).values(
   'month'
).annotate(
   amountSum=Sum('amount')
)
```